# Help identify wood & stain for tongue & groove + beam cabin ceiling popular in Poconos (and possibly other woodsy areas)

Tags: wood, woodworking, staining, wood-finishing, tongue-and-groove

I have cathedral popcorn ceilings in my house and am looking to reproduce a tongue & groove + beam type ceiling that is/was very popular in a lot of chalet type houses in the Pocono mountains (and likely other mountainous type areas): [image: https://imgur.com/a/DW45Bhu]. I saw over 50 houses while house shopping in the area over the summer and a lot of them had this type of ceiling at least in some parts of the house. They all look very similar in style, wood and color but I cannot for the life of me find anyone that knows what type of wood or stain was used. This looks like the closest thing in terms of wood: https://www.homedepot.com/p/8-ft-x-4-in-x-5-16-in-Knotty-Pine-Edge-V-Plank-Kit-6-Piece-VSV7-88-6-244-ST-HOMEDEPOT/202535999 but I'm really not sure what to get in terms of stain. Any ideas?

Comment: I agree it looks like knotty pine; as far as stain, why not try a few small pieces with a few light stains and see if you like how it turns out?

Comment: It almost looks like a dark Tung oil finish to me

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yea, that's what I plan to do - however, since I saw this in so many houses I figured there might be a specific popular finish that was used. In terms of staining / tung oil - should I finish it with some sort of polyutherane / laquer after or would it not need the added protection on the ceiling?

Comment: I don’t believe additional protection would be needed for a ceiling or elevated area.